How to go about finding the minimal conditions guaranteeing that such a matrix is invertible?
I am working on an economic input-output model, and I want to find the conditions under which a system of linear equations determining the equilibrium yields a unique solution. I have an equation of the form $ Ax = b $ where A is an $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ square matrix such that:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} \Delta_{11} - 1 & \Delta_{12} & ... & \Delta_{1n} & \phi_{1} \\
\Delta_{21} & \Delta_{22} - 1 & ... & \Delta_{2n} & \phi_{2} \\
... \\ \Delta_{n1} & \Delta_{n2} & ... & \Delta_{nn} - 1 & \phi_{n} \\
\lambda_{1} & \lambda_{2} & ... & \lambda_{n} & 0
 \end{pmatrix} $$
Where the only constraints are that $ \Delta_{ij}, \lambda_{i}, \phi_{i} \in [0,1) $, $\forall i,j $, and that:
$$ \begin{gather*} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\Delta_{ij} + \phi_{i} = 1, \text{ } \forall i \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i} = 1 \end{gather*} $$
Now, my question is: how would I go about finding the conditions that guarantee that this matrix is invertible? I was trying to use Gaussian elimination to find some conditions, but the problem seemed to be too general for this method. I don't think that calculating determinants is a feasible method either with a matrix like this. Are there any theorems, lemmas, or results in particular that I should be aware of when approaching this problem?
My background is in economics, and so far I know three methods with which invertibility can be proved: by using Gaussian elimination, by calculating the determinant, and by looking at whether there are any eigenvalues equal to zero, none of which seem to work here.

what do you know about the eigenvalue $1$ for $\begin{pmatrix} \Delta_{11}  & \Delta_{12} & ... & \Delta_{1n} & \phi_{1} \
\Delta_{21} & \Delta_{22} & ... & \Delta_{2n} & \phi_{2} \
... \ \Delta_{n1} & \Delta_{n2} & ... & \Delta_{nn} & \phi_{n} \
\lambda_{1} & \lambda_{2} & ... & \lambda_{n} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ ?  Without knowing OP's background knowledge these sorts of questions aren't feasible to answer.

The conditions say that you are looking at a Markov model. You may know that. In either case that's a place to look for invertibility conditions for this particular kind of matrix.

Thank you all, it might be above my level but I will look into these!

Beware of people using fancy sounding words and phrases like “ fairly sophisticated”

One can go a bit further. Writing the matrix as:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} \Delta - I & \phi \ \lambda^{T} & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
We can add the first n columns to the n+1st column to get a matrix B: $$ B = \begin{pmatrix} \Delta - I & 0 \ \lambda^{T} & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ We know that the determinant of matrices A and B are equal. By Schur's formula, if $ \Delta - I $ is invertible, then we have that: $$ det(A) = det(B) = det(\Delta - I) $$ For my purposes, even if it is not a minimal condition, $ \Delta - I $ being invertible is sufficient - but I don't know what guarantees that.
